# Varies result for SQL function and Query

Tags: mysql, sql, function, where-clause, and-operator

I have a SQL function that contains a simple Select Count query, and it gives the correct result when running the query in SQL mode whereas the result is different when the same query is used in a function. Both scenarios are as here;

**1. SQL Query**

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM responses WHERE batch='2K18' AND degree_program='BSC' ;
```

**2. SQL Function**

```
BEGIN
       DECLARE ResponseCount INTEGER;
       SET ResponseCount = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM responses WHERE batch=BATCH AND degree_program=DEGREEPROGRAM);
    RETURN (ResponseCount);
END
```

The result of **SQL Query** is correct whereas when used in the **SQL Function** it only checks the second parameter of where clause. what could be possible solution.

Comment: **never** use variable names the same as your column names,

Answer (score 0):

To me, this is suspicious:

```
WHERE batch=BATCH AND degree_program=DEGREEPROGRAM); 
      -----------
      this
```

How come? Because you named column and parameter **the same**, so it *evaluates* to something similar to `where 1 = 1` which is always true, i.e. you don't filter data on the 1st parameter at all.

On the other hand, the 2nd parameter's name differs from column name (which has underline in its name).

Generally speaking, it is good if you accept naming conventions according to *best practices* and name parameters using prefix as `par_` or `i_` (as "in" parameter) or anything else you find appropriate.

Therefore, if your query looked like

```
... SET ResponseCount = (SELECT COUNT(*) 
                         FROM responses r 
                         WHERE r.batch          = PAR_BATCH 
                           AND r.degree_program = PAR_DEGREE_PROGRAM);
```

it might work as you expected.